# Project cant't find DynamicComponent : Blazor

Tags: .net, blazor, webassembly, .net-6.0

**SOLVED**: *solution at the end*

I am trying to use the DynamicComponent but it says,

[image]

if "Ctrl + ." it suggests me to create a razor component.

Here what I have or tried so far:

- VS 2022 version 17.0.0 Preview 2.1
- Blazor WASM Project Property "Target framework" set to .NET 6.0

Package Manager:

```
dotnet --version
6.0.100-preview.6.21355.2
```

- deleted bin, obj folders
- rebuild project and solution

Any Idea what am I missing?

Best Alex

EDIT::

```
dotnet --info
```

[image]

EDIT2::
Code-snippet: **Tabs.razor**

```
@page "/tab"
<h3>Tabs</h3>
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
<h1>Loan application</h1>

<select @onchange="OnChange" class="form-control">
  <option value="@nameof(Tabs)">Select a value</option>
  <option value="@nameof(HundeVersicherung)">Hunde</option>
  <option value="@nameof(ReiseVersicherung)">Reise</option>
</select>
<h1>start</h1>

<DynamicComponent Type="selectedType" />

@code {
    Type selectedType = typeof(Tabs);

    public void OnChange(ChangeEventArgs changeEventArgs)
    {
        selectedType = Type.GetType($"InsuranceProductsUI.Pages.{changeEventArgs.Value}");
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }  
}
```

Code-snippet: **Hundeversicherung.razor**

```
@page "/hunde"
@using InsuranceProductsUI.Components

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <Search OnSearchChanged="SearchChanged" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <HundeVersicherungTable ProductAs="ProductAsList" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <Pagination MetaData="MetaData" Spread="2" SelectedPage="SelectedPage" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Project page screenshot:

[image]

Namespace screenshot:

[image]

*Even though it doesn't recommend me for an update in .net6.0. I manually had to update the Microsoft packages and the Automapper.*

***before (not working):***

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MimeKit" Version="2.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

***after (working):***

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21355.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21355.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.12" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.12" />
      <PackageReference Include="MimeKit" Version="2.14.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.12" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Usually, I ignore these "errors" as buggy Intellisense, since 90% of the time the code will successfully build and run.  Does your code run?

Comment: Hi,
found the solution...
even though it doesn't recommend me for an update in .net6.0.
I manually had to update the Microsoft packages and the Automapper.

Comment: I'm glad you lost the error, but I'm pretty sure is has nothing to do with Automapper.

Comment: Yeah (initial error were the MS-packages but than static errors occured), this was due to updating the Microsoft packages, 
because  Errors occured afterwards, so I checked: Manage Nuget Package 
and there was an update for Automapper, even though the numbers before and after are the same.

but I am 100% there was no Automapper update before ^^